# Drap and drop not working in iframe PHP and JS

Tags: jquery, iframe, drag-and-drop

We have applied the drag and drop files process in our PHP page using jQuery, which is working fine. But when we are opening the same page in iframe, it's not working fine. When we drop the file, it is opening in a new tab instead of uploading.

Here is the code that we are using:

```
<div class="dnd-widget msg-menu-close" id="messages-list" ondrop="dragAndDropFilesInMessageBox(event);" ondrag="dragAndDropFilesInMessageBox(event);" tabindex="3" style="overflow: hidden; outline: none;"></div>
```

As code point of view, we are using just PHP and jQuery.

What can we try to fix this?

Comment: This does not seem to have enough information in the question to replicate the problem. Voting to close for now.

Comment: Its solved, drag n drop doesn't work in iframe  in crome